# What is a unicode character or even a glyphicon for ⏭ but with only one triangle

Tags: text, unicode, font-awesome, glyphicons

In a YouTube playlist, the button to proceed to the next video looks like ⏭︎︎︎ but with only one rightward triangle.

I've been searching https://glyphsearch.com and http://shapecatcher.com/ but haven't found anything closer than ⇥ or ►.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single Unicode codepoint for exactly what you are looking for.  The closest I could find is:

```
U+23EF BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE WITH DOUBLE VERTICAL BAR
⏯
```

Otherwise, you can combine multiple codepoints together, eg:

```
U+25B6 BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE
U+23B8 LEFT VERTICAL BOX LINE
▶⎸
```

```
U+25B8 BLACK RIGHT-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE
U+23B8 LEFT VERTICAL BOX LINE
▸⎸
```

```
U+2BC8 BLACK MEDIUM RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE CENTRED
U+23B8 LEFT VERTICAL BOX LINE
⯈⎸
```

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to hear better answers, but this will work for now:

```html
Watch the next video by clicking 
<div class="youtubeNextBtn" style="display: inline-block; width: 40px; vertical-align: middle; margin: -10px;">
    <svg height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 36 36" width="100%" ><use class="ytp-svg-shadow" xlink:href="#ytp-id-13"></use><path class="ytp-svg-fill" d="M 12,24 20.5,18 12,12 V 24 z M 22,12 v 12 h 2 V 12 h -2 z" id="ytp-id-13"></path></svg>
</div>
in the player
```

I'm using the same SVG code that YouTube uses.